Fatal error on random blog posts
Some of our blog posts are randomly being effected and at the footer it's saying "There has been a critical error on this website." I enabled the Debug mode, and there seems to be an issue with the comments.php file that's in the custom theme we use. When I rename it to old, the blog goes back to normal. However, I don't think it should be kept that way.See the error below. The site is running on PHP 8.3, WP 6.5.2
The theme was custom developed by another company. Please note, I'm not a developer, so please respond in a way I could understand lol. I appreciate the feedback - thanks in advance!
PS: The quick fix was duplicating the post and re-publishing it. However, that's a lot of work. And now, WP won't even let me change the year back to 2022.
Here's the error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function twentyseventeen_get_svg() in /home1/schnakel/public_html/mls312/staging/wp-content/themes/High-Performance-Framework-master/comments.php:85 Stack trace: #0 /home1/schnakel/public_html/mls312/staging/wp-includes/comment-template.php(1617): require() #1 /home1/schnakel/public_html/mls312/staging/wp-content/themes/High-Performance-Framework-master/single.php(120): comments_template('comments.php') #2 /home1/schnakel/public_html/mls312/staging/wp-includes/template-loader.php(106): include('/home1/schnakel...') #3 /home1/schnakel/public_html/mls312/staging/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/home1/schnakel...') #4 /home1/schnakel/public_html/mls312/staging/index.php(17): require('/home1/schnakel...') #5 {main} thrown in /home1/schnakel/public_html/mls312/staging/wp-content/themes/High-Performance-Framework-master/comments.php on line 85

Pretty simple.  comments.php is trying to call a function twentyseventeen_get_svg() which doesn't exist: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
You'll probably need to contact the theme developer or, just find the part of the code in comments.php (line 88) that calls the function and comment it out.
Looks like that function comes with the theme twentyseventeen but yo're not using twentyseventeen

Thank you. That worked. I kept the old comments.php file just in case. Do we really even need this file since we don't use comments at all? We still get the email notifications from spammers, but you don't see the comments on the site.

Whatever theme you're using should come with it's own version of comments.php.  Best advice - delete it, go back to the page that creates the error and see what happens (the page obviosuly references comments.php - see what happens without it (If your theme has a fallback)
